# MySql Syntax error - 42000

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting this error :

```
Warning: PDO::query() [pdo.query]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'When, RDV, Comments FROM distributions WHERE IDFond = 1' at line 1 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/JG/DistributionManager.class.php on line 56
```

When executing this code :

```
$Distribution_Manager->getListByFunds($Selected_Fond->id());

    foreach ($Distribution_Manager as $Distrib)
    {
        echo $Distrib->Comments();
    }
```

Here is the concerned function :

```
  public function getListByFunds($FundID)
  {
    $Distribution = array();

    $q = $this->_db->query('SELECT id, IDClient, IDFond, Who, When, RDV, Comments FROM distributions WHERE IDFond = '.$FundID);

    while ($donnees = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
      $Distribution[] = new Distribution($donnees);
    }
    return $Distribution;
  }
```

Should be a little mistake but I'm lagging on it for almost 50 minutes ! 
Thanks in advance for the help ;)

Comment: are you suing this code in some framework

Comment: @Venkat does it matter? It's an SQL error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`When` is mysql keyword, try this

```
SELECT id, IDClient, IDFond, Who, When AS anything..
```

or enclose this keyword to backquotes

```
SELECT id, IDClient, IDFond, Who, `When`, RDV..
```

Comment: Well done ... I was sure that was something awkward  ! Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 3):

`WHEN` is a [mysql reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), so try using a different column name or enclose `WHEN` in backquotes.

Comment: Well done ... I was sure that was something awkward  ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Give back quotes for column names like `id` and try it

Answer (score 0):

You're never closing your quotes on your statement.